# Unable to run shell script using dockerfile

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker

I am new to docker and I just wanted to copy the shellscript inside the container and I wanted to execute the shellscript.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazonlinux

WORKDIR /opt

ADD ./test_Install.sh /opt/test_Install.sh

RUN chmod 777 /opt/test_Install.sh

WORKDIR /

RUN ./test_Install.sh
```

Build image: `docker build -t "testinstallscript:dockerfile" .`

When I use the command `"docker build -t "testinstallscript:dockerfile" ."` I get the following error:

> standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or
>   directory"
>
> The command '/opt/test_Install.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: That's not what `RUN` is for, change it to `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`.

Comment: should be `./opt/test_Install.sh` it seems

Comment: or better change `WORKDIR` to `/opt` but `RUN` still needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `RUN ./test_Install.sh` to utilize `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`.  `RUN` executes commands in a new layer creating new image so use it when setting up your container.

Answer (score -1):

The below command worked: 
  RUN bash /opt/test_install.sh